# Another Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I need a little help developing my SQL query. My goal is to remove an entry. My condition is two tables away. I've gotten this far but I can't seem to find where the other mistake

```
con.Execute "DELETE FROM Expenses INNER JOIN Agreements ON Agreements.AgreementsID = 
             Expenses.AgreementID AND INNER JOIN Audits 
             ON Audits.AuditID = Agreements.AuditID WHERE Audits.Share = True"
```

I'm using access 2007 and my con variable is

```
con.Open _
"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
"Dbq=" & Loc & ";"
```

Comment: Can you run that sql directly, ie without using vba?  You might want to test it with a select query first.

Comment: No still breaks. Same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, You are using `AND` before `INNER JOIN`, remove that only.

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW Expenses.* 
  FROM Expenses 
           INNER JOIN Agreements ON Agreements.AgreementsID = Expenses.AgreementID 
           INNER JOIN Audits ON Audits.AuditID = Agreements.AuditID 
  WHERE Audits.Share = True
```

**[EDIT Query]**

```
  DELETE Expenses.* 
  FROM Expenses 
  WHERE Expenses.AgreementID IN (
                         SELECT Agreements.AgreementID FROM Agreements 
                         INNER JOIN Audits ON Audits.AuditID = Agreements.AuditID
                         WHERE Audits.Share = True
                        )
```

OP get error:- Too few parameters Expected 2.

**To handle this**, This error may be obtained because the any column names being selected have special characters in it. If there are special characters in the column names of the database, the name should be surrounded with brackets in the SQL query. So if you have any column name which have special char value , then try [ColumnName]

Comment: Now the error I'm getting is [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in the query expression 'Agreements.AgreementID = Expenses.AgreementID INNER JOIN Audits.AuditID = Agreements.AuditI',

Comment: @see one more time, I added DISTINCTROW in query

Comment: what the Audits.Share conatins, if these are bool column then use 0 or 1 instead of True/ False

Comment: Try Edit Section Query

Comment: Too few parameters Expected 2

Comment: Are you executing query directly in ms-access or via code

Comment: Via Code. But I think I'll head back to updating each with Record Sets. They worked (literally) half the time but at least they were working. I was hopping to convert to direct sql to improve its robustness but I'm spending way to much time on this. Thanks everyone for taking the time to try this.

Comment: I think now query work fine, something you are missing from code while you are using recordset?

Comment: Even in direct copy paste to Access gives the same errors. I know sql and use it with php but for some reason Access is breaking me.

Comment: This error may be obtained because the any column names being selected have special characters in it. If there are special characters in the column names of the database, the name should be surrounded with brackets in the SQL query. So if you have any column name which have special char value , then try [ColumnName]

Comment: so any column contains special characters value?